# Prevent URL viewing in android webview

Tags: android

The the webview url in android is visible in android logcat while debugging in eclipse . How can I prevent others to view this url in eclipse as a security measure?

Comment: add to your <application> tag in your manifest android:debuggable="false"

Comment: Seems a bit pointless, as there are other ways to figure out which URLs the device is accessing.

Comment: could you provide some links to do the above in alternative ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest file, add this :

```
<application
    android:name="com.MyApplication"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you all for your precious solutions...  [android:debuggable="false"] solved the issue....